# Seaborn plotting diferent graphs with the same code

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

Here is the deal:

if i call this function

**def plotagem (title, labelx, labely, x, y, data):**

```
sns.set_palette('Accent')
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
ax = sns.lineplot(x = x, y = y , data = dataset)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(12,6)
ax.set_title(title, loc='left', fontsize = 18)
ax.set_xlabel(labelx, fontsize = 14)
ax.set_ylabel(labely, fontsize = 14)
ax = ax
```

**plotagem('Vendas cafelura 2017 e 2018', 'Tempo', 'Vendas', 'mes', 'vendas', data = cafelura)**

i'm receiving this result:

[Output with function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3nTy.png)

as soon as i write the code, not calling the function "plotagem" but with all the same inputs:

```
sns.set_palette('Accent')
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
ax = sns.lineplot(x = 'mes', y = 'vendas' , data = cafelura)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(12,6)
ax.set_title('Vendas cafelura 2017 e 2018', loc='left', fontsize = 18)
ax.set_xlabel('Tempo', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_ylabel('Vendas', fontsize = 14)
ax = ax
```

i receive this output:

[Output without function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NwI3.png)

Any ideas? if i further "normalize" the Output 1, the i wont even be able to call to function

Ex.:

I have this data set:

[dataset.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmE8p.png)

if i use the raw code, not calling the function, i get this output when plotting "vendas_normalizadas":

[plotting with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBRwQ.png)

Now... if use the function, i will receive this error:

[plotting with function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HihbO.png)

**ValueError: Could not interpret value `vendas_normalizadas` for parameter `y`**

Any ideias?
Thansk all!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

ax = sns.lineplot(x = x, y = y , data = **dataset**)

This line was calling other dataset named "dataset" already inside the function

```
sns.set_palette('Accent')
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
ax = sns.lineplot(x = x, y = y , data = **dataset**)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(12,6)
ax.set_title(title, loc='left', fontsize = 18)
ax.set_xlabel(labelx, fontsize = 14)
ax.set_ylabel(labely, fontsize = 14)
ax = ax
```

Newbie me